# Struts 2 how to access into properties from an index

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have my page index.jsp, i need to access to a list of products, to show the newest products.

I can't access to this list because it's the index and no one calls the action to fill the list that i need, and i don't know how to fill that list or access to the variable in the action.

Comment: Redirect to some action from index page.

Comment: I've been thinking in that solution, but i believe that it wasn't correct, is that the only way?

Comment: Accessing actions not JSP-s **is** the correct way.

Comment: You can make an index action that will forward to the jsp page. In other ways look how convention plugin treated an index action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call your index.jsp page.it automatically calling your bean and retrieve the list_of_records shown in same index.jsp page.

use < s:bean > in your jsp page.

index.jsp

```
<s:bean name="controller.ActionClass" var="my">//use your action
</s:bean>

<s:iterator value="my">
   <s:property value="list_of_records"/>
</s:iterator>
```

package controller
ActionClass.class

```
private List list_of_records;

public List getList_of_records() {
    list_of_records = new ArrayList();
    list_of_records.add("one");
    list_of_records.add("two");
    list_of_records.add("three");

   //do your stuff here,record collecting from database or something.

    return list_of_records;
}

public void setList_of_records(List list_of_records) {
    this.list_of_records = list_of_records;
}
```